# Does nacre/mother-of-pearl have a greater compressive strength than human bone?

Tags: biochemistry

Exactly what it says on the tin: as measured in mPa, does [nacre](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nacre)/mother-of-pearl have a greater compressive strength (i.e. it can take getting squeezed more before breaking) than human bone?

I recognize that it's rather brittle and doesn't do well with shear loading, but that's not the question here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Yes.

According to [this article](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/19627773/), the compressive strength of nacre is $300{-}500\;\mathrm{MPa}$, whereas the compressive strength of [human bones](http://silver.neep.wisc.edu/%7Elakes/BoneAniso.html) ranges up to around $200\;\mathrm{MPa}$.